# Parameter update during function call

Tags: python

So, I am writing a code to shift the elements of a particular list within a list of lists towards right.

```
def right(state,index):
    r_state=state
    new_state = []
    for j in range(1,len(r_state[index])):
        new_state.append(r_state[index][j-1])
    new_state.insert(0, r_state[index][-1])
    r_state[index]=new_state
    return r_state

#case1
for i in range(2):
    print(right([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]], i))

#case2
def printer(node):
    for i in range(2):
        print(right(node, i))

printer([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
```

case 1 gives me the output that I want(only one sublist corresponding to the index changed):

```
[[4, 1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [8, 5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

But case 2 ends up updating my list of lists

```
[[4, 1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
[[4, 1, 2, 3], [8, 5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Why is the list being updated? Also, how can I modify case2 to get the same output as case 1?

Comment: Because you are explicitly mutating the list you pass into the function. `r_state = state` *does not make a copy. Assignment never makes a copy in Python*

Comment: Also, your `printer` function already uses `print`, so if you `print` the result of calling that function you will get `None` since the funciton doesn't return anything.

Comment: Why do you use `r_state=state`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that assignment does not make a copy in Python. You have to explicitly copy. In your own code, to copy the list, change

```
r_state = state
```

To

```
r_state = state[:]
```

Also, you will see `r_state = list(state)` used as well. Python 3 has the even more explicit:

```
r_state = state.copy()
```

You can also use a list-comprehension to make a new list. Here is a quick-and-dirty approach using modular arithmetic to shift the elements of your sequence:

```
>>> def shift_right(lst, shift):
...     modulus = len(lst)
...     return [lst[(i + shift)%modulus] for i in range(len(lst))]
...
>>> def right(state, index):
...     return [shift_right(sub, 1) if i == index else sub for i, sub in enumerate(state)]
...
>>> test =  [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
>>> shift_right(test[0], 1)
[2, 3, 4, 1]
>>> shift_right(test[0], 2)
[3, 4, 1, 2]
>>> shift_right(test[0], 3)
[4, 1, 2, 3]
>>> shift_right(test[0], 4)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> shift_right(test[0], 5)
[2, 3, 4, 1]
>>> right(test, 0)
[[2, 3, 4, 1], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
>>> right(test, 1)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8, 5], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

That last comprehension is perhaps a bit too dense, and could be written like this instead:

```
>>> def right(state, index):
...     result = []
...     for i, sub in enumerate(state):
...         if i == index:
...             result.append(shift_right(sub, 1))
...         else:
...             result.append(sub)
...     return result
...
>>> right(test, 0)
[[2, 3, 4, 1], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
>>> right(test, 1)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8, 5], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
>>> right(test, 2)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [10, 11, 12, 9], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
>>> right(test, 3)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [14, 15, 16, 13]]
>>>
```

Comment: Learned something new today.Thanks!